# Images refuse to show up in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, image

I have a form that allows users to upload multiple images:

```
<form method="post" action="/submitWorkOrder" id="work-order-form" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    {{ csrf_field() }}
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="priority">Attach Image(s)</label>
        <input type="file" class="form-control" id="work-order-images" name="work-order-images[]" multiple/>
    </div>
</form>
```

And the following in my controller:

```
public function submitWorkOrder(request $request) {
    
    $uniqueID = uniqid("wo-");
    $woStatus = "incomplete";
    $errors = 0;
    $errorString = "";

    if($request->hasFile('work-order-images')) {
        $allowedfileExtension=['pdf','jpg','png','gif','tif','bmp','svg','psd','eps'];
        $files = $request->file('work-order-images');

        foreach($files as $file){
            $filename = $file->getClientOriginalName();
            $extension = $file->getClientOriginalExtension();
            $check=in_array($extension,$allowedfileExtension);

            if($check) {
                $filename = $file->store('public');
                $image = new Image;
                $image->name = $filename;
                $image->parent_id = $uniqueID;
                $image->save();
            } else {
                $errors++;
                $errorString = "Incorrect Image Type Uploaded.";
            }
        }
    }
    
    if ($errors == 0) {
        return redirect('/work-orders')->withSuccess("Work Order Successfully Created");
    } else {
        echo $errorString;
    }   
}
```

And finally, in my blade template, I have:

```
@foreach($images as $image)
    <img src="{{asset('storage/app/'.$image->name)}}"/>
@endforeach
```

When I go to the URL that has that markup, it spits out a broken image, with the SRC of:
http://127.0.0.1:8000/storage/app/public/l536mgPiNvjrAB15w41X2ka9CcGdkY8sNltEK9n1.png

If I push it live to the server, the URL is the same, except instead of http://127.0.0.1:8000, it replaces it with the live URL of the site.

I have checked the file path, and the image IS there. The image is uploading. It is storing the file name in the database exactly as the image has been named. I just can't seem to display it.

I have also tried the following:

- Replaced {{asset('...')}} with {{url('...')}} in the image SRC path.
- Tried using {{ storage_path }} / {{$image->name }} for the image SRC path.
- I tried running the command: php artisan storage:link

At this point, I'm out of ideas. The path seems to be correct. The image does exist on the server. Just doesn't seem to want to display.

Any thoughts?

Comment: Can't you try storing image in the public folder rather than storing in the database?

Comment: Well - I am doing both. The images get uploaded into the storage/app/public folder - but, I need a record of what images were uploaded with the work order that is submitted. There are additional form details that are submitted along with the image. And so - I need a way to know what images belong to which work order. Does that make sense?

Comment: Yes that does. Should i provide my logic what i have done in my project? Will you be able to figure out via that?

Comment: Can I see how are you passing the Images in the blade?

Comment: if you used the `storage:link` command then the URL should be `yoursite.test/storage/imagehere.png`

Comment: @lagbox - That did it!! That was driving me nuts. Thank you so much!

Comment: Do you need to create symlink? can you check what is the directory where images are getting stored, public directory or storage directory ?